# Difference between context.getTheme.obtainStyledAttributes and context.obtainStyledAttributes in View Class

Tags: android, difference

What is the difference between `context.getTheme.obtainStyledAttributes()`
and `context.obtainStyledAttributes()`?

Is Theme is my app style?

Answer (score 7):

It 's the same.

in Context.java

```
 /**
 * Retrieve styled attribute information in this Context's theme.  See
 * {@link android.content.res.Resources.Theme#obtainStyledAttributes(int[])}
 * for more information.
 *
 * @see android.content.res.Resources.Theme#obtainStyledAttributes(int[])
 */
public final TypedArray obtainStyledAttributes(@StyleableRes int[] attrs) {
    return getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
context.getTheme.obtainStyledAttributes()
```

and

`context.obtainStyledAttributes()` both yield the same outcome, the latter is just a shorthand way without directly invoking the themeStyle.